# Trying to see if $f(x,y)=xy+1-\sin\left (\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ is differentiable at $(1,5)$

Tags: limits, functions, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to find out if this function is differentiable at $(1,5)$:

> $$f(x,y)=xy+1-\sin \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$

First I've checked that it's continuous at the point $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,5)}{f(x,y)}=f(1,5)=6-\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

After that I've calculated it's partial derivatives:

$f'_x=y - x \cos\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ and $f'_y=x$

Now I'm trying to see if it's differentiable by the limit definition:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (1,5)} \frac{\left| xy+1-\sin \left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) - \left(6-\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right) - \left(y - x \cos\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right) (x-5) - x (y-5)\right|}{||(x,y)-(1,5)||} = 0$$

But I can't work my way around it... am I right by doing all of this? Is there another way? How can I solve it?

Comment: FYI, This isn't functional analysis.

Comment: Can you suggest a more suitable tag? @Sean

Comment: This may help you: http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/differentiability-multivariable-real-functions-part1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is differentiable at $c$ if partial derivatives exist at $c$ and are continuous.

Comment: @JoaquinRomera She meant that the partial derivatives are continuous

Comment: Oh great... I deleted my comment, thanks.